# How to force the editor to save the document without setting a dirty status

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp

How can I update an editor without triggering the PROP_DIRTY?

This is the method that I use to update my editor document. This will trigger the PROP_DIRTY if it's successful.

```
textEditor.getDocumentPRovider().getDocument( getEditorInput() ).set( "update text editor here" );
```

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make sense. It *is* dirty if you changed the contents. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @nitind I'm trying to force an update to my document without triggering the PROP_DIRTY because it will ask the user to CTRL + S or Save the workspace.

Comment: Ok, but *why*? For instance, why doesn't it open with those contents?

Comment: @nitind because I have to modify the document based on the users input after it is saved.

Comment: What modification? *Why?*